# Notify user when data are inserted in the table with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Right now i am developing a web app with ASP.net MVC5. I would like to notify the admin when data are inserted in the table with bootstrap badge. Like the notification on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have some sample code or something?

Comment: To be honest, i would like a road map to guide me. I am thinking about SignalR but i am too sure. @br4d.net

Answer (score 1):

@GeatanSobze I think the best way for you to do that is by using SignalR.. SingnalR is a library that makes you communicate in real time...
Check out this [link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)